# Does Tezos have anything similar to Ethereum's events?

Tags: node, rpc

In Ethereum you can subscribe to events through a node and you can then get notified if a specific event, like the receiving of a token transfer, happens. Is this possible with Tezos?

Comment: There is an on-going work on the off-chain events standard on top of TZIP-16, stay tuned: https://gitlab.com/tzip/tzip/-/blob/master/proposals/tzip-20/tzip-20.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are no events currently in Tezos. It has been discussed, but AFAIK there are no fixed plans to add it. This might change in the future though.

Comment: Understood. Thanks!